# Switching off Notification from device

Tags: iphone

How can we switch off notification from device?

Comment: I am referring to Push Notification here. Let say server is pushing me some notifications. How can I stop that from my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remote (Push) Notifications**

If you are talking about remote (push) notifications, you can unregister for remote notifications using the `- (void)unregisterForRemoteNotifications` method in UIApplication (see the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.htmlre-register.)).

However, Apple notes that users can disable push notifications on their own:

> You should call this method in rare
>   circumstances only, such as when a new
>   version of the application drops
>   support for remote notifications.
>   Users can temporarily prevent
>   applications from receiving remote
>   notifications through the
>   Notifications section of the Settings
>   application. Applications unregistered
>   through this method can always
>   re-register.

**Local Notifications**

If you're talking about local notifications, you can use the `- (void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` or `- (void)cancelAllLocalNotifications` methods, also on UIApplication (see the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

Comment: Thank you for your response. My concern is about push notification. Can I disable them through device? I mean not thru code something in settings of device?

Comment: Yes, as it states in the blockquote from Apple in my answer: "Users can temporarily prevent applications from receiving remote notifications through the Notifications section of the Settings application."

Comment: Thanks you so much. I missed that line :).